# How to set the selected option

Tags: php

I'm trying to get selected option in select,I need to make a select from my database and use id to mark which category is set.

```
echo"<select>";
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat1))
{  if ($row['biljka_id']==$GET['b']) {
echo "<option value=".$row['biljka_id']." selected='selected' >".$row['naziv']."</option>";
} else { echo "<option value=".$row['biljka_id'].">".$row['naziv']."</option>";
}
echo"</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the short code.

You need not use `if else` statement as you need to justify only one variable depending upon condition.

You can do it with ternary operator.

```
<?php
echo "<select>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat1)) {
    $selected = ($row['biljka_id']==$GET['b']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value=".$row['biljka_id']. $selected ">".$row['naziv']."</option>";
}
echo"</select>";
?>
```

[Rererence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't properly close your `while` loop or the `else` part of your if, depending on how you look at it. Plus, why not use concatenation instead. So, you might re-write your code as follows:

```
$selectStr = '';
$selectStr .= "<select>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rezultat1))
{  
   if ($row['biljka_id']==$GET['b']) 
   {
      $selectStr .= "<option value='".$row['biljka_id']."' selected='selected' >".$row['naziv']."</option>";
   } 
   else 
   { 
      $selectStr .= "<option value='".$row['biljka_id']."'>". $row['naziv']. "</option>";
   }
}
$selectStr .= "</select>";

echo $selectStr;
```